# I would like to replace a <w:tab /> element with a new xml element <w:t> </w:t> in a Open XML document using XQuery

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, xquery-sql

## Here is a sample of the XML document before I run my XQueries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone='yes'?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"   xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
  <w:body>
   ...
 <w:p w:rsidR="00BB265E" w:rsidRDefault="00BB265E">
     <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="DefaultText"/>
    <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="720"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>1.7</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    **<w:tab/>**
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="001C1D1B">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FABF8F"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Member means any person who is enrolled in</w:t>
  </w:r>
 ...
```

## Here is some of the XQueries I tried to run:

## Query 1

```
UPDATE XML_TORTEST
  SET XMLDOC =  updateXML(XMLDOC,'declare namespace w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"; /w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:tab',
                     XMLType('<w:t> </w:t>'))
  WHERE XML_TORTEST_ID = 1
 AND XMLExists('$p/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:tab'
                  PASSING XMLDOC AS "p");
```

## This gives this error:

SQL Error: ORA-31013: Invalid XPATH expression
31013. 00000 -  "Invalid XPATH expression"
*Cause:    XPATH expression passed to the function is invalid.
*Action:   Check the xpath expression for possible syntax errors.

## Query 2 - Works, but XML output is not correct (not literally)

```
 UPDATE XML_TORTEST po
  SET po.XMLDOC =
    XMLQuery('declare namespace  w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";     
              copy $i := $p1
              modify
              (
             for $j in $i/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:tab
             let $newn := ''<w:t> </w:t>''
             return replace node $j with $newn)
             return $i' PASSING po.XMLDOC AS "p1"
          RETURNING CONTENT)
 WHERE XML_TORTEST_ID = 1
 AND XMLExists('declare namespace w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"; $p/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:tab'
              PASSING po.XMLDOC AS "p");
```

## Here is the sample XML after I ran Query 2:

```
 <w:p w:rsidR="00BB265E" w:rsidRDefault="00BB265E">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="DefaultText"/>
        <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="720"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
      <w:t>1.7</w:t>
  </w:r>
    **<w:r>&lt;w:t&gt; &lt;/w:t&gt;</w:r>**
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="001C1D1B">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FABF8F"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Member means any person who is enrolled in</w:t>
  </w:r>
  ....
```

Any help to convert the `&lt;w:t&gt; &lt;/w:t&gt;` into `<w:t> </w:t>` is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `let $newn := <w:t> </w:t>` instead of `let $newn := ''<w:t> </w:t>''`.

Comment: If I remove the '' and change the $newn := <w:t> </w:t> the <w:tab /> gets replaced with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add magic word `(#ora:invalid_path empty #)`.More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5996) paragraph "Oracle XQuery Extension-Expression Pragmas"

```
UPDATE XML_TORTEST po
  SET po.XMLDOC =
    XMLQuery('
            declare namespace  w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";   
              (#ora:invalid_path empty #){
              copy $i := $p1
              modify
              (
             for $j in $i/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:tab
             let $newn := <w:t></w:t>
             return replace node $j with $newn)
             return $i
             }
             ' PASSING XMLDOC AS "p1" 
          RETURNING CONTENT);
```

Comment: I tried the update statement above, but no luck. It creates an empty text node. Like this `<w:r>
        <w:t>1.7</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"/>
      </w:r>` I need one that has a space character in it.

Comment: I am able to create a node, but only if I put a value in it. Like this: ` UPDATE XML_TORTEST po ...
 ...
                 let $newn := <w:t>### </w:t>
                 return replace node $j with $newn)
                 return $i}' PASSING po.XMLDOC AS "p1"
              RETURNING CONTENT)
 WHERE XML_TORTEST_ID = 1 ...` But now I have to find a way to remove the ### characters so that only the space remains.

Comment: `select xmlquery('let $spaceChar:= "&#32;"  return <aaa>{$spaceChar}</aaa>' returning content) from dual;` Try this. And probably you can remove (#ora:invalid_path empty #) from code